# ¿Utilizar onBackPressed en un Fragment para poder navegar hacía atrás dentro un WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview-android, onbackpressed

Poseo un problema, tengo una aplicación móvil que maneja WebViews dentro de Fragments, lo que sucede es que cuando ingreso a alguno de estos WebViews y empiezo a navegar, presiono la tecla de ir para atrás del celular y directamente cierra la aplicación en lugar de volver a la página web anterior, que es lo que necesito.

este es el código del archivo Java del fragment.

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


public static WebView browserMain;

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    WebView browserMain = rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_hWB);

    String url = "file:///android_asset/nitro/biologia/indexBiologia.html";
    browserMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    //browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pages/html/search.html");
    browserMain.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
    browserMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    return  rootView;


}

public static boolean onBackPressed(){
    boolean rtn = false;
    if(browserMain.canGoBack()){
        browserMain.goBack();
        rtn = true;
    }
    return rtn;
}


}
```

Este es el código del XML del Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/main_hWB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Dentro del MainActivity también incluí un WebView que funciona perfectamente con este código

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (browser.canGoBack()) {
        browser.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();

    }

}
```

Código de actividad principal.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import java.util.List;

import static com.example.promo.promo.R.color.colorPrimaryDark;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
WebView browser;
NavigationView navView;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.content_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
    final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    browser= findViewById(R.id.main_WB);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    //browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pages/html/search.html");
    browser.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(browser, true);
    }else {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pages/html/main.html");
    } else {
        browser = findViewById(R.id.main_WB);

    }


    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(new int[]{colorPrimaryDark});
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    browser.reload();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (browser.canGoBack()) {
        browser.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }

    if(!MainFragment.onBackPressed()){
        //Fijate que acá estoy terminando el activity, pero podrias hacer otra cosa.
        finish(); //El webview del fragment no tiene mas donde volver y salgo del Activity.
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId ();

    if (id == R.id.inicio) {
        // Handle the camera action

        boolean fragmentTransaction = false;
        MainFragment fragment = null;

        fragment = new MainFragment ();
        fragmentTransaction = true;


        if (fragmentTransaction) {
            getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ()
                    .replace ( R.id.main_WB, fragment )
                    .commit ();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Quisiera hacer lo mismo con los WebView de los Fragments.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hago en estos casos es atrapar el evento como vos estás haciendo en el activity con `onBackPressed()`.

Pero antes de procesar el evento en el `Activity`, invoco un método sobre el `Fragment` indicándole que se presionó el botón back.

A lo que el `Fragment` me puede responder true si se hizo cargo del evento, o false si debo procesar el evento como enviado al `Activity`.

Cuando el `Fragment` recibe el evento, checkea con su `WebView` igual que hiciste en el `Activity`. Si el `WebView` tenía donde volver, vuelve, y el `Fragment` devuelve `true`. En caso contrario, el `Fragment` devuelve `false`, y el `Activity` puede determinar si debe terminar o hacer otra cosa.

En el `Fragment` incluir un método:

```
public boolean onBackPressed(){
    boolean rtn = false;
    if(browserMain.canGoBack()){
        browserMain.goBack();
        rtn = true;
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

En el `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(!fragmentVisible.onBackPressed()){
        //Fijate que acá estoy terminando el activity, pero podrias hacer otra cosa.
        finish(); //El webview del fragment no tiene mas donde volver y salgo del Activity.
    }

}
```

**EDICION I**

Mirando el código del main activity, para implementar esta solución, necesitas definir el MainFragment como un atributo del Activity de forma de poder referenciarlo en diferentes métodos, en lugar de hacerlo una variable local a onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item).

Haciendo esto el atributo estará disponible en `onBackPressed()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    WebView browser;
    NavigationView navView;
    /* *** Agregar *** */ 
    //Para tener la referencia al fragment fuera de onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    MainFragment mainFragment = null;
    // Pensando en que vas a tener mas fragments, este string tendría que indicar cual 
    // es el activo para no enviar mensanes a un fragment que no está visible. 
    String fragmentActivo = null;
    ...
```

Luego en `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean eventoProcesado = false;
    if(fragmentActivo != null && fragmentActivo.equals("MainFragment")){
        eventoProcesado = mainFragment.onBackPressed();
    }
    // De forma similar podes llamar onBackPressed() en otros fragments futuros.

    //Si eventoProcesado es falso es porque MainFragment no hizo Back y dejamos que el activity procese el evento.
    if(!eventoProcesado){
        if (browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Finalmente en `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId ();

    if (id == R.id.inicio) {
        // Handle the camera action

        boolean fragmentTransaction = false;

        //Quitar el tipo de dato para declaración, porque ahora es un atributo de la clase
        fragment = null;  // <---

        fragment = new MainFragment ();
        fragmentTransaction = true;


        if (fragmentTransaction) {
            getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ()
                    .replace ( R.id.main_WB, fragment )
                    .commit ();
            fragmentActivo = "MainFragment"; //  <-- Cuando el fragment activo cambia 
            // hay que cambiar este valor para que el activity no le envíe
            // mensajes de onBackPressed().
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
       ...
```

*Para después:*

Esta solución funciona, pero se podría mejorar creando una interface `BackPressedAware` que tenga el método `public boolean onBackPressed();`, y haciendo que los diferentes fragments implementen esta interface.

Luego, en lugar de usar un `String` para saber cual es el `Fragment` que está visible, directamente usas una variable "`fragmentActivo`" de tipo `Fragment` que justamente referencie al fragment activo.

Y como es `BackPressedAware`, en el `onBackPressed()` del `Activity`, con verificar que no sea null, se puede llamar directamente `((BackPressedAware) fragmentActivo).onBackPressed()` evitando un if por cada `Fragment` distinto.

Comment: Lo siento pero sigue sin funcionar, me obligaron a hacer el método onBackPressed del MainActivity estático, así como los WebView que van dentro del onBackPressed  del Fragment, tendrá algo que ver?

Comment: No se quien te está obligando, pero si agregas el código de la actividad principal a la pregunta lo vemos.

Comment: Listo, ya está agregado.

Comment: Revise el código del activity, y adecué al respuesta a lo que estas haciendo. Principalmente, declaré el MainFragment como atributo de la clase en lugar de variable local, y agregué una variable para saber en todo momento, en el activity, cual es el fragment que está visible, para saber si se le debe o no mandar el mensaje de onBackPressed(). Fijate dónde dice Edición I.